# Creating bi-directional relation between two nodes using the neo4jphp function "relateTo"

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

I create a relationship as the following in Neo4php

```
$src->relateTo($dst, 'FRIENDS')
    ->setProperty('duration', '5')
    ->save();
```

I want the relationship be undirected not directed. 
If I am not wrong we can do this in Cypher

```
create n-[:FRIENDS]-m
```

vs

```
create n-[:FRIENDS]->m
```

How about in Neo4jphp?  Can we set "relateTo" to a bi-directional relationship?

Answer (score 8):

Neo4j does not support undirected relationships. What you are asking for is impossible.  Why do you want undirected relationships? If the direction doesn't make sense for your domain, just pick a direction arbitrarily and ignore it when traversing or querying.

Comment: We can do this in cypher, create n-[:likes]-m vs create n-[:likes]->m, you mean the above two commands are the same?

Comment: I thought n-[:likes]-m meant "n-[:likes]->m OR n<-[:likes]-m". At least, that's how I've used it, when I don't care what the direction of the relationship is.